# Laravel count results in controller or view

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

**Logic:** A user has many credits.

Controller:

```
public function getAdminAccount()
{
    $company = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
                ->companies()
                ->with('users.credits')
                ->first();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.admin.account',
                array('company' => $company));
}
```

My controller function is returning the correct data in JSON data I need, however, I want to count the results, per `user_id`, preferably before they're shown in the view.

JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":"4",
      "user_id":"4",
      "credits":"10",
      "created_at":"2013-09-30 09:39:25",
      "updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "id":"67",
      "user_id":"4",
      "credits":"6",
      "created_at":"2013-08-05 12:40:25",
      "updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   }
][
   {
      "id":"6",
      "user_id":"6",
      "credits":"9",
      "created_at":"2013-06-25 16:24:18",
      "updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "id":"69",
      "user_id":"6",
      "credits":"2",
      "created_at":"2014-01-16 10:09:55",
      "updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   }
]]
```

So, for that JSON result, it should say something like:

1. user_id:4, total credits: 16
2. user_id:6, total credits: 11

To my knowledge, it's beneficial to format the JSON within the controller, not the view. I have tried the `->sum()`, `->groupBy()`, functions, to no success.

Thank you.

**Update**

```
public function getAdminAccount()
{
    $company = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
                ->companies()
                ->with('users.credits')
                ->get()
                ->sum('credits');
    $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.admin.account', array('company' => $company));
}
```

The above function adds the total number of credits together, which is very close to what I need! I just need the number of credits for each user that makes up that total!

**Update**

Using this forloop seems to return the correct MYSQL logic, but not the correct values still:

```
@foreach ($company->users as $user)
{{ $user->credits()->count('credits') }}<br>
@endforeach
```

**MYSQL:**

```
select count(`credits`) as aggregate from `usages` where `usages`.`user_id` = '4'
```

Comment: Not an answer but why do you run a query to get only the id and then another one to get the whole company with the id? Continuing with `with` after `companies()` should be enough.

Comment: Because the request corresponds with the user's company. So the initial line figures out what company the user is assigned to, and then I have the company's ID to get the user's credits.

Comment: `$company = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->companies()->with('users.credits')->first();` ?

Comment: Thank you, it makes my query more efficient, however, I still cannot count the credits of each user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `sum` not `count` but anyway using it in the loop means n+1 issue, so you'd better do this:

```
// User model
public function creditsSum()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Credit')
        ->selectRaw('user_id, sum(credits) as sum') // user_id must be in select to match the models
        ->addSelect(DB::raw('count(*) as count')) // that just in case you also need 
                                                  // credits count, if not remove
        ->groupBy('category_id');
}

// Then you can access it as easily as every relation:
User::with('creditsSum')->get();

// you will have eager loaded data on each user model:

$user->credits_sum->sum;
$user->credits_sum->count; // if you select it too
```

Comment: Hi Deczo, thank you for your reply. If you see my current function, I need to find the user_ids of only the ones who are related to the authenticated user's company. Hence the first line, get the company ID which belongs to the user, and then all other users with that corresponding ID. I've just checked the MYSQL and it's searching for all users.

Comment: Yeah sure it does, it was just a sensible example. But it works just the same for any query builder, which is `Auth::user()->companies()->with('users.creditsSum')->first();`. And does user have many companies?

Comment: @Svengali Yes it's strange to just use `first` on companies because that sounds like there is only one company per user. So maybe the wrong relationship defined?

Comment: A user can belong to many companies and a company has many users. It's identified by a pivot table. Got you Deczo, it now only pulls the IDs of who belong to that company. `{{$company->credits_sum->sum}}` returns property of none object however?

Comment: It belongs to the users so something like this: `foreach($company->users as $user) {{ $user->credits_sum->sum }}`

Comment: Thanks Deczo, unfortunately this is popping up - `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$sum`

Comment: This does the trick - `{{ $user->credits_sum->first()->sum }}`. Thank you Deczo! Again!

Comment: You are absolutely right and Laravel is right too ;) Change the relation to hasOne like in my edit as hasMany returns Collection of course. My fault

Answer (score 0):

If I predict your db layout the right way, I think a join is the fastest solution. That way you don't need to fire a query per user. It is also `SUM` and not `COUNT`, count would just count the amount of datasets.

```
$company->users()->join('credits', 'users.id', '=', 'credits.user_id')
                 ->selectRaw('SUM(credits.credits) as `total_credits`, users.username')
                 ->groupBy('credits.user_id')->get();
```

This should give you something like

```
total_credits | username
------------------------
           24 | John
           12 | Michael
```

You should use `leftJoin` if you also want to get the users without any credits.